# Exam class: 'answer' instead of 'solution'

Tags: exam

In `exam` class, how to print `Answer` instead of `Solution` when using

```
\begin{solution}

\end{solution}
```

in question-answer format?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Referencing `Section 8.3.1` of [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/exam/examdoc.pdf), you can use, for example,

```
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Answer}\par\noindent}
```

Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Answer}\par\noindent}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}{}
\question who is this?
\begin{solution}
    it's me
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```